# Cloud Functions for Firebase Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have request function and tryng to integrate width Cloud Functions for Firebase.

```
var http = require("https");

    function addUserToMailchimpList(email) {
    var options = { method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://usxx.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/xxxxxxx/members/',
      headers: 
       { 'content-type': 'application/json',
         'user' : 'anystring:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
       },

      body: 
       { email_address: email,
         status: 'subscribed',
       },
      json: true };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);
      console.log(body);
      console.log(error);
      console.loh(response);
    });

}
```

Then I am tryng to deploy width this function

```
exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
  const user = event.data; // The Firebase user.
  const email = user.email; // The email of the user.
  const displayName = user.displayName; // The display name of the user.

  return addUserToMailchimpList(email);
});
```

but in firebase functions log I am getting error:

```
Error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND usxx.api.mailchimp.com usxx.api.mailchimp.com:443
```

what I am doing wrong? not undestand.. ?

other method I am tryng to use but same error

```
function addUserToMailchimpList(email) {

  var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "hostname": "usxx.api.mailchimp.com",
    "port": null,
    "path": "/3.0/lists/xxxxx/members/",
    "headers": {
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "user": "anystring:xxxxxxxxxx",
    }
  };

  var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
    var chunks = [];

    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    res.on("end", function () {
      var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
      console.log(body.toString());
    });
  });

  req.write(JSON.stringify({ email_address: email,
    status: 'subscribed',
    merge_fields: { FNAME: 'xxx', LNAME: 'xxx' } }));
  req.end();

}
```

Comment: `usxx.api.mailchimp.com` can't be resolved into an IP-number. Either the hostname is invalid, your DNS doesn't know about it, some antivirus-/firewall-software is blocking lookups, etc.

Comment: I am deployng from localhost, but functions are executed from firebase

Comment: Perhaps you're not allowed to create network connections from Firebase? [This blogpost](https://www.automationfuel.com/firebase-functions-sending-emails/) suggests that in order to make external API requests, you need to enable billing.

Comment: yes seems this is reason why I am getting error. thanks

Comment: you can add this as answer, so I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This blogpost](https://www.automationfuel.com/firebase-functions-sending-emails/) suggests that before you can perform API request from a Firebase Cloud Function, you need to enable billing first.